# Error when running SonarQube scan: ERROR: Failed to parse file [FILENAME] at line 27: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: vue.js, sonarqube

I'm having some issues running a scan of Vue.js code with SonarQube. I'm running the scan using SonarQube scanner (installed with yarn)

```
yarn sonar-scanner
```

[SonarQube Scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner)

The scan appears to go well, the scan does complete and I do get a list of items to fix on the SonarQube dashboard - however at some point I receive a wall of errors like these in the middle of the scan:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse file [FILENAME] at line 27: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

This happens regardless of whether it's importing a component or just a module like Axios.

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import Component from '@/src/js/global/component';
```

**Things i've looked at**

1. Make sure sourceType is set to 'module' in .eslintrc.json => It is set to module
2. Checking if there is a Vue.js specific configuration for SonarQube => Do not see any specific documentation regarding configuring SonarQube for Vue.js
3. Saw the following post, but not using TypeScript:
   [SonarQube-Scanner fails to analyze Vue files - Failed to parse file [.vue]](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-scanner-fails-to-analyze-vue-files-failed-to-parse-file-vue/17751)

Anyone suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I'm having exactly the same issue. I have a vue.js project (no typescript) and SonarQube is saying: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AlbertRannetsperger were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I just get rid of this error stopping importing dynamically inside components declarations

```
  components: {
    BasicTab: () => import('./Tabs/BasicTab'),
```

I moved all the imports to the beggining of the  statement

```
import BasicTab from './Tabs/BasicTab'
```

It may not be the solutions but at least this error is gone